# Handling complex layer bounds in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leaflet to overlay various WMS map layers over a basemap. Each covers a different geographic area but there can be some overlaps and none of the layers is a perfect rectangle - they are polygons with multiple sides. I'm currently doing this by setting the bounds on each layer to the rectangle which contains all the tiles for that layer, but my problem comes when I zoom down into areas where the two maps overlap - first, I am getting a lot of failed requests because both sources are queried for tiles (and the boundary isn't a straight line), but also if I want to display an error tile (e.g. for when a WMS service is offline), any layer which doesn't contain that point will display the error tile, often over the top of other layers which have tiles in that area.

Is there a way of specifing a more complicated bounds value for a layer (i.e. a many-sided polygon), or is this something I can handle differently in terms of clipping?

Any help appreciated. Many thanks.